# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'entity_effects' when running PooledOLS

Tags: python

```
from linearmodels.panel import PooledOLS
```

When I run a panel regression using PooledOLS, I got an error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'entity_effects'
```

I was confused because I followed [the documentation](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/models.html) closely in running `PooledOLS`, which has '`entity_effects`'.

Below is what I did:

```
year = pd.Categorical(data2.year)
id= pd.Categorical(data2.id)
data2 = data2.set_index(['id', 'year'])
data2['year'] = year
data2['id'] = id
exog_vars = ['sep_value', 'weight', 'year', 'id']
exog = sm.add_constant(data2[exog_vars])
mod = PooledOLS(data2['roe'], exog, entity_effects=True, time_effects = True)
pooled_res = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PooledOLS actually does not have 'entity_effects'. You probably looked at PanelOLS instead which does have 'entity_effects'.

According to the note there's no such thing as PooledOLS with entity and time effects as true

> If both entity_effect and`time_effects` are False, and no other effects are included, the model reduces to PooledOLS.